# Beautiful Soup error [Violation] Avoid using document.write()

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download all images with class top_s and top_sl , it was working for a few pages but then it stopped , HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME , [Violation] Avoid using document.write().

This is my python code -

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = 'https://goodlogo.com/top.250/n/250/interval/6'

sourcecode = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
plain_text = sourcecode.text
soup = bs(plain_text, 'html.parser')


path = 'C:/Users/roysu/Desktop/src_code/Python_projects/python/web_scrap/myPath/'


link = soup.select(".top_s3l")
for tag in link:
    my_images = tag.get('src')
    path_new = my_images.replace("/images/logos/small/", "")
    file_name = path+path_new

    full_name = 'https://goodlogo.com'+my_images
    sourcecode1 = requests.get(
        full_name, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    file = open(file_name, "wb")
    file.write(sourcecode1.content)
    file.close()


link1 = soup.select(".top_s3")
for tag1 in link1:
    my_images1 = tag1.get('src')

    path_new1 = my_images1.replace("/images/logos/small/", "")
    file_name1 = path+path_new1

    full_name1 = 'https://goodlogo.com'+my_images1
    enter code here
    sourcecode1 = requests.get(
        full_name1, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    file = open(file_name1, "wb")
    file.write(sourcecode1.content)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Does this throw an error for u? It ran perfectly fine on my system.

Comment: it doesnt show an error but after scraping for a few pages it doesnt download anymore , i checked the console it showed the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you're looking for in the first place, but I wrote this for fun, because why not. It's 2020, the pandemic is all over the place, and I don't have anything better to do on a Friday evening.

This is basically a slightly improved version of your scraper, written solely for educational purposes, of course. It fetches all `150` logos per page (apart from the last one, as there are about 50) in a rather slow manner, pausing for at least a second before grabbing another logo image.

You can control the scraper with `get_next_page(first_page=2, last_page=3)`. This, for example, will download all logos from both page `2` and `3`. If you, however, wish to grab'em all, just remove the arguments, like this `get_next_page()` and let it run.

I'm using a bunch of tricks that might be new to you, for example, [generator pipe lines](https://brett.is/writing/about/generator-pipelines-in-python/) and [decorator(s)](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

Feel free to read up on these or just jump head-first into the code and explore / enjoy.

Anyhow, here's the code. Feedback is more than welcomed!

```
import functools
import os
import random
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

STARTING_URL = "https://goodlogo.com/top.250/n/250/interval/"
TAG_CLASS = 'top_s3'
DOWNLOAD_DIR = "logos"
HEADERS = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36",
}


def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Finished {func.__name__!r} in {run_time:.2f} secs.")
        return value
    return wrapper_timer


def make_logo_dir():
    os.makedirs(DOWNLOAD_DIR, exist_ok=True)


def get_next_page(first_page: int = 1, last_page: int = 8) -> str:
    page_offset = 1
    yield from (
        f"{STARTING_URL}{page_number}" for page_number
        in range(first_page, last_page + page_offset)
    )


def update_headers(current_page: str):
    HEADERS["referer"] = current_page


def get_page_source_code(page_url: str) -> str:
    return requests.get(page_url, headers=update_headers(page_url)).text


def make_soup(page_string: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    return BeautifulSoup(page_string, "html.parser")


def get_img_src(soup):
    yield from (
        i['src'] for i in soup.find_all("img", {"class", TAG_CLASS})
    )


def parse_source(img_src: str) -> tuple:
    image_name = img_src.split('/')[-1]
    source_url = f"https://goodlogo.com/images/logos/{image_name}"
    return image_name, source_url


def download_logo(image_source: iter):
    for item, image in enumerate(image_source, start=1):
        file_name, source_url, = parse_source(image)
        print(f"Fetching logo #{item}: {source_url}")
        save_logo(file_name, source_url)


def save_logo(file_name: str, source_url: str):
    with open(os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, file_name), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(source_url, headers=HEADERS).content)
        pause_for_awhile()


def pause_for_awhile(max_seconds: int = 5):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, max_seconds))


@timer
def download_logos():
    make_logo_dir()
    for page in get_next_page():
        print(f"--- Current page: {page} ---")
        download_logo(get_img_src(make_soup(get_page_source_code(page))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_logos()
```